# Racket Keyword used as an expression

Tags: syntax, racket, keyword

I try to write a program that adds in the source code the string "hello world". The name of the file in source.rkt. It gives me this error:

```
source.rkt:6:31: #%datum: keyword used as an expression in: #:mode
  #(118 6)
```

This is the code:

```
#lang racket

(provide (all-defined-out))

(define out (open-output-file "source.rkt"
                             [#:mode 'text               
                              #:exists 'can-update]))

(write "hello world" out)

(close-output-port out)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The brackets are not literals. They mean optional. Therefore, the correct syntax is:

```
(define out (open-output-file "source.rkt"
                              #:mode 'text               
                              #:exists 'can-update))
```

Comment: Are there any better solutions that also allow me to see the code in DrRacket as it updates?

Comment: I don't really understand the question, and don't think that it relates to the current question. Perhaps you should ask a new question on a new post with more details?